# Is it possible to transfer money from one paypal account to another without touching my paypal account, but I get notified when the payment happened?

Tags: paypal, automation, payment-processing, marketplace

Is it possible to transfer money from one PayPal account to another without touching my paypal account, but I get notified when the payment happened?

scenario:

1. Seller on my website uploads product
2. Buyer comes on the website and purchase
3. If Seller receives the amount from buyer
4. Me (the websites unlock product for download (money dosen't touch the websites account)

coding Language dosen't really matter, if not possible is it possible to a business account with automated payout to the seller?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be addressed to PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

- Use PayPal Checkout with [a server backend](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/)
- Specify a `payee` object in the `purchase_unit`: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/